# Is there a way to merge facebook share count of a url with variations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two urls.

1) example.com/cat-slug/article-slug
2) example.com/cat-slug/article-slug?param

URL 1 has FB Total count 17 and url 2 has FB total count as 26. How can I see that these are merged and I get a total share count of 43.

I added meta property="og:url" but this only shows us the url count of url 1 not the merged total count.

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could influence this by setting the `url` of the like button to your base url to `example.com/cat-slug/article-slug`.

How do you use the like button?

Comment: that was present from before... the like button was already preset to example.com/cat-slug/article-slug ...  

URL 2 was shared directly on facebook... not via the like button... its got more counts than url 1 ... I don't know who created url 2